# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ethanhua.skeleton.SkeletonAdapter cannot be cast to me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2.BindingRecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, kotlin, skeleton-code

I am trying to use the skeleton loading library(https://github.com/ethanhua/Skeleton) with data binding
and for recycleView I am using the collection adapter library(https://github.com/evant/binding-collection-adapter)

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ethanhua.skeleton.SkeletonAdapter cannot be cast to me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2.BindingRecyclerViewAdapter
at me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter2.BindingRecyclerViewAdapters.setAdapter(BindingRecyclerViewAdapters.java:19)
at com.coroutinedemo.databinding.FragmentTodoListBindingImpl.executeBindings(FragmentTodoListBindingImpl.java:209)
```

Please help to get rid of it.

Edit:

Get the [Source code](https://github.com/shivangbtech/ExceptionSample) here.

Comment: Please share your code for more clarity

Comment: @KishanMaurya I am sharing the git repo link for the source code. https://github.com/shivangbtech/ExceptionSample

Comment: I will check this

Comment: Inside this . var skeletonScreen = Skeleton.bind(binding.rvTodo)
            .adapter(binding.rvTodo.adapter)
            .load(R.layout.list_item_todo)
            .show()

You have to pass your TODO adapter.

Comment: @Kishan, In that case, we have to create an adapter for that and we can not take benefit of binding-collection-adapter.

Comment: Binding will not provide the adapter implementation. That you have to create.

Comment: @Kishan I also tried using adapter "MyRecyclerViewAdapter<T> extends BindingRecyclerViewAdapter<T>". I have pushed the code on the git repository.

Comment: I will check fro repo